# Paperclip and Cocoon, images not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem

I have Item Model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

and Image Model

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  has_attached_file :picture, :styles => {:medium => "600x600>", :thumb => "100x100>"},       :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
end
```

And in the controller, the strong parameters go

```
def item_params
  params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :price, images_attributes: [:picture, :_destroy])
end
```

just as the Cocoon READM says.
So the basic idea is that an Item has several Images, which in turn have this paperclip field `picture`. Then the form is being rendered with Coccon

```
#views/admin/items/new.html.erb
<div class="field">
  <div class="ui teal label">Imagen</div>
  <%= f.fields_for :images do |image| %>
    <%= render partial: 'image_fields', :f => image  %>
  <% end %>
</div>

#views/admin/items/_image_fields.html.erb
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.file_field :image, :class => "add-image-field" %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "Eliminar", f, :class => "ui red mini button" %>
</div>
```

In the view everything seems to work fine, but then looking at the parameters sent to the controller, something is wrong:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"AIogvRQuKNrAAOjM7YsnVQx7j2MwZ1VC3LiZy0cDDrU=", 
"item"=>{
  "name"=>"", 
  "description"=>"", 
  "price"=>"12345", 
  "images_attributes"=>{
    "1394577880921"=>{
      "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000003182718 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140311-27326-19i0obp>, @original_filename="blue-diamond-rings.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"item[images_attributes][1394577880921][image]\"; filename=\"blue-diamond-rings.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, 
 "commit"=>"Crear"}
```

What's that weird signature after images_attributes? It's ruining the Item saving process.

Thanks for any pointer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call the file_field `image` and it should be `picture`.

The rest is fine.

What is "weird" inside `image_attributes`:

- "1394577880921": a temporary id, which will be replaced with a real id when the item is saved to the database. This is how rails handles nested attributes. When parsing the posted params, rails will convert this to an array of `Image`s.
- the value of `image` (which should be named `picture`) is the file-data, which looks weird of course

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it. Great gem by the way!

Comment: @nathanvda,  If I want to show the preview of the uploaded image what should I do? Can I get this temporary ID?